# Futures contract month code

Tags: futures

In futures contracts, the [delivery month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delivery_month) is reflected in the symbol name with a letter code. The letters for all 12 months in order are `F, G, H, J, K, M, N, Q, U, V, X, Z`.

Where do these letters come from? It seems they were picked somewhat arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are alphabetical, with the omission of certain letters which I assume could be mistaken for numbers, (except perhaps P, and R, like 8?)

They're taken from the back end of the alphabet, ending in Z (ironically like 2), probably to avoid B and D.

Example futures chain: http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_product_calendar_futures.html

**Addendum**

This theory is slightly contradicted by the option naming convention:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_naming_convention

But options may have developed some time after the futures convention was created.

Answer (score 0):

Like most jargon, its compression. Literally they wanted an unambigeous way to display the month and year of expiry in two characters so you could fit more information on a board of limited character set size. Futures traded on exchanges far before electronic systems.

Now we are stuck with the convention and its a pain for electronic systems as they are only unique in limited contexts.